# SQL query to return data corresponding to all values of a column except for the min value of that column

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I have a table with the following columns:

```
userid, datetime, type
```

Sample data:

```
userid  datetime               type
   1    2013-08-01 08:10:00     I
   1    2013-08-01 08:12:00     I 
   1    2013-08-01 08:12:56     I
```

I need to fetch data for only two rows other than the row with min(datetime)

my query to fetch data for min(datetime) is :

```
SELECT  
    USERID, MIN(CHECKTIME) as ChkTime, CHECKTYPE, COUNT(*) AS CountRows
FROM
    T1
WHERE 
    MONTH(CONVERT(DATETIME, CHECKTIME)) = MONTH(DATEADD(MONTH, -1,
CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())))
    AND YEAR(CONVERT(DATETIME, CHECKTIME)) = YEAR(GETDATE()) AND USERID=35
    AND CHECKTYPE='I'
GROUP BY 
    CONVERT(DATE, CHECKTIME), USERID, CHECKTYPE 
HAVING 
    COUNT(*) > 1
```

a lil help'll be much appreciated..thnx

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this will help you:

```
WITH CTE AS 
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY userid ORDER BY checktime) RN
    FROM dbo.T1
    WHERE CHECKTYPE = 'I' 
    --add your conditions here
)
SELECT * FROM CTE
WHERE RN > 1
```

Using [CTE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) and [`ROW_NUMBER()`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) function this will select all rows except min(date) for each user.

**[SQLFiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8143a/1)**

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM YOURTABLE A
INNER JOIN
(SELECT USERID,TYPE,MIN(datetime) datetime FROM YOURTABLE GROUP BY  USERID,TYPE )B
ON
A.USERID=B.USERID AND
A.TYPE=B.TYPE 
WHERE A.DATETIME<>B.DATETIME
```